# Testing Nokogiri XML for Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rspec, tdd, nokogiri

Using RSpec How could/should I test to ensure elements exists and have specified values

In my example I'm looking to ensure I have an EnvelopeVersion with a value 1.0, i would also like to see a test just to ensure EnvelopeVersion  exists

```
def self.xml_header
   builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.Root{
     xml.EnvelopeVersion "1.0"
  }
   end
   builder.to_xml
end
```

I've tried this, but it failed undefined method `has_node?' for #

```
it 'should create valid header' do
   doc = GEM::xml_header
   doc.should have_node("EnvelopeVersion ")
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution can be simplified:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(GEM::xml_header)    
doc.xpath('//Root/EnvelopeVersion').text.should eq("1.0")
```

can be simplified to:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(GEM::xml_header)    
doc.at('EnvelopeVersion').text.should eq("1.0")
```

Nokogiri has two main "find-it" methods: [`search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search) and [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at). They are generic, in that they accept both XPath and CSS accessors. `search` returns a NodeSet of all matching nodes, and `at` returns the first Node that matches.

There are also the methods [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) and [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) if you want something a bit more mnemonic, along with [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) and [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using nokogiri in my tests to parse the generated xml and query it

```
require 'nokogiri'

describe 'function' do
  describe '.xml_header' do
    it 'should create valid header' do
        doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(GEM::xml_header)    
        doc.xpath('//Root/EnvelopeVersion').text.should eq("1.0")
    end     
  end
end
```